# How to get URL parameters in JSP using Strust2 OGNL

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

I am trying  to get parameter from the URL using Struts2 but it's not working. I can get it using EL but not with the Struts2.

`showReport` is passed in the URL.

Using JSTL and EL it works

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.showReport eq true}">
        <a href="#x" style="width:155px" title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onclick="document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit()"><span>Export E-Sign Information</span></a>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${param.showReport eq false}"></c:when>
        <c:when test="${empty param.showReport}"></c:when>
</c:choose>
```

S2 way

```
<s:if test="%{param.showReport=='true'}">
        <a href="#x" style="width:155px" title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onclick="document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit()"><span>Export E-Sign Information</span></a>
</s:if>
```

I need to do it using S2 OGNL not sure what I am dong wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.showReport}">
    <a href="#x" style="width:155px" title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onclick="document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit()"><span>Export E-Sign Information</span></a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
</s:else>
```